# Eye protection for someone who does not wear glasses?

Tags: safety

I can see well without glasses or contact lenses.

What form(s) of eye-protection are convenient, provide good protection, and do not cause fogged vision?

I assume that I need protection against both things that I can see (in front of my eyes), and things that are off to the sides.  Wrap-around goggles (even with holes for ventilation) tend to fog up, and keep me from seeing what I am working on.

Comment: heat the goggles before wearing them

Comment: One of my friends in college always joked that he was wearing his "safety contacts." I haven't had much luck when trying to track him down in recent years, but I hope he still has both eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that specific product recommendations are not appropriate, so I use these as an example of the type:

[image]

I have found this style to be very comfortable and non-fogging. I often end up wearing them into the house without realizing they're still on my face.

<sup>I will note that this brand tends to be "wallet light" at my local big-box store.</sup>

Answer (score 9):

I will make two suggestions:

1. Close fitting, OSHA approved, polycarbonate 'wrap around' glasses. They look similar to the fake Oakley sunglasses I foolishly bought as a kid. They are surprisingly comfortable compared to something like goggles.
2. If you have goggles, but don't like the fogging, trying 'Defogging Liquid/wipe'. These are available readily and often make a huge difference in your visibility.

Personally, I prefer polycarbonate, as I feel it tends to naturally fog up less. I will say my 'Stealth Safety' brand lab goggles form college still hold up and are very comfortable with great ventilation. However, at $35-55 they are not as easy on the wallet.

Comment: These can also be shaded or just clear with UV protection for outdoor use. Very comfortable.